# Is it a good pattern to use (cascade = CascadeType.ALL) for all @oneToMany relations by default?

Tags: java, jpa, orm, one-to-many, cascade

I have seen that most of times developers use `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` by default for all `@OneToMany` relations in JPA. but is it a really good pattern? imagine we do an "update" for an entity, does it start a very long chain of update action for all related entities that are related to each other? for example :

doing a simple update for a class entity will start this chain :
update(class) => update(student) => update(course) => ...

Comment: Terrible idea. Each relation should be on a case-by-case basis. Do you really expect to do cascade delete on every relation??!

Comment: @NeilStockton : dear Neil, i agree you. but try it for example with netbeans auto generate entities from database. it generates cascade = cascadeType.All for many of the oneToMany relations by default !